# Корректная работа свойств vw и vh

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять как работает свойство `vw` и `vh`.

На [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) пишет:

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width;
>  
>   1vh = 1% of viewport height

Но, например, у меня ширина окна 768рх, по этому когда я выставляю `font-size: 100vw` по логике размер шрифта должен заполнить 768рх, или нет? А то у меня залезает значительно дальше 768рх.

P.S. Уже не одну статью перечитал, и никак не могу понять как корректно вычислить зависимость расширения экрана от значения `vw/vh`.

Пример в песочнице:
https://jsfiddle.net/obats/wf6vu3a8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-units) хорошо написано по этому поводу:

> Что такое «размер шрифта»? Это вовсе не
>   «размер самой большой буквы в нём», как можно было бы подумать.
>
> Размер шрифта – это некоторая «условная единица», которая встроена в
>   шрифт.
>
> Она обычно чуть больше, чем расстояние от верха самой большой буквы до
>   низа самой маленькой. То есть, предполагается, что в эту высоту
>   помещается любая буква или их сочетание. Но при этом «хвосты» букв,
>   таких как р, g могут заходить за это значение, то есть вылезать снизу.
>   Поэтому обычно высоту строки делают чуть больше, чем размер шрифта.

Так что измерить размер шрифта с помощью каких-то стандартных формул не получится, более того разные шрифты имеют разные размеры этих запасных отступов.

Сам обычно использую для шрифта метод подбора, он заключается в том, что в отладчике подбирается подходящее значение в px соотносимое со значением в vh или в vw, а дальше уже используется коэффициент. Например, если 14px = 2.8vh, то получается коэффициент 5, сл-но 20px/5 = 4vh.

**UPD.**

В роли отладчика для сравнения шрифтов выступает обычный браузерный отладчик, например, в Chrome. Пишите в css так:

```
.class {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 2.8vh;
}
```

А дальше уже играете с чекбоксами в отладчике включая/выключая нижнее значение и подгоняя размер в vh, пока перестанете замечать разницу от включения/выключения.

Comment: Насколько я понял значение `font-size: 100vw` придает значения не фразе отдельно, а конкретной букве? Если это так, тогда все логично.
Спасибо за наводку.

Но есть вопрос по вашему процессу подбора размера шрифта. На счет коэффициента понял (как я понимаю коеф. разный под разные расширения экрана?). Но вот как реализована у вас самая "техническая" составляющая? Что выступает в роле "отладчика"?

Comment: Коэффициент меняется в зависимости от кегля, обычно под мобильные устройства кегель нужен больше, и соответственно vh или vw будет больше. Если кегель не меняется, то значение будет одинаковое под разные разрешения. По поводу отладчика добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> font-size: 100vw
> ```

А должно быть `100vh`.

https://jsfiddle.net/wf6vu3a8/1/

```css
html {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #FF4136;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Questionable</h1>
```

Дальше - разница в `line-height` и `margin` у `body` вызывают скролл.

Answer (score 1):

1vh = 1% от **высоты** размеров окна. В вашем же примере попробуйте изменить высоту окна с результатом.

**UPD:** Возможно проблема в самом jsfiddle. На http://codepen.io/Ostroffskiy/pen/ORVRKR ваш код

```
html {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #FF4136;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

прекрасно работает.

Comment: Уже поправил пример. Случайно не тот параметр вставил)